# How can I redirect active URLs in Shopify?

Tags: url, redirect, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-template

I would like to redirect certain pages on my Shopify store but i’m unable to do so using Shopify’s URL redirects page as the pages in question are active. Is there a way to do the redirects myself using code?

An example, i’d like to redirect the /cart page to the homepage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hacky solution but if we combile javascript and template names , we can redirect people to homepage when they land on '/cart' to homepage.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. That sounds a bit out of my scope I think - I only know very basic coding

Comment: When implementing this JavaScript-based redirection, it's crucial to keep in mind that it may not function correctly if a user's browser has JavaScript disabled. Users could briefly encounter the cart page before the redirection takes effect, as it triggers after the page has loaded. To ensure a seamless experience for all users, it's highly recommended to rigorously test its compatibility across a wide range of browsers and devices. You can use it when JS is disabled`<noscript>
  <p>Please click <a href="desired_page.html">here</a> to continue.</p>
</noscript>`